# Can we still use amcharts4 with newer versions of Node.js?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, amcharts

I had a project made with Vue 2 (node.js version 14.19.3) where amcharts4 library was used. Now I'm trying to migrate this project to Nuxt 3 (node.js version 20.11.0) but I can not make amcharts4 work properly there. Is there any chance to continue using amcharts4 or it's better to move to 5th version?

Earlier I tried launching my Nuxt project with 19 version of node, and graphs made with amcharts4 worked with errors but still didn't make at least 500 error. After moving further to 20.11.0 I see graphs stopped working at all, when I try to load their page I get
"Class extends value undefined is not a function or null" error. I have one js file where function to init graph is defined, this file is then imported in my vue component. No matter what code I add to this file, it seems that only the fact that amcharts4 library is being used causes problem (that's why I don't add code to this question).

Comment: The question doesn't make sense in general, it's specific to your case. It's unknown what was the setup with V2. If it was not Nuxt then you compare two totally different cases that aren't tied to Node verson. Since this isn't Nuxt lib, you most likely have to prevent it from being rendered on server side at least to not cause compatibility problems, it's unknown if you did that. The case with Node 19 isn't representative because odd versions are experimental and will have additional problems when compared to even versions